# Is there a way to build CLI with no dependencies required?

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

Recently I though about scaffolding a little CLI with Ruby, but was concerned about using it on a machine with no Ruby installed. I've searched for examples of popular CLI's and found that [Docker CLI](https://github.com/docker/cli) is built with [Go language](https://golang.org/). I'm able to use this CLI on my computer with no Go installed. How can one build a tool that will not require you to install Ruby?

My guess is that there's a build process involved and it might be compiled to something present on most systems, like shell or smth. Sorry if this is a lame guess/question!

Comment: Check out this project https://github.com/pmq20/ruby-packer

Comment: Hey @Yakov, thank you for the link! This is exactly what I need. This solves the problem, but I'm still curious about how this works under the hood. Hopefully, I'll be able to explore it on my own from now or maybe someone will explain the inner workings behind packaging under this question :)

Comment: it just creates a file putting together your code + a copy of ruby interpreter, so you're shipping a copy of ruby within your project :)

Comment: You MUST have Ruby installed to run a Ruby script. Ruby is an interpreted language, not compiled. Someplace on the machine you'd have to have a Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(note: this is not a detailed answer, just a summary of how it works)
Cli programs are just as other programs, there is nothing special about them.

Go is a compiled language - a program called "compiler" takes the go code and translate it directly to machine language, following the conventions imposed by an operative system. It becames pure 0 and 1, no references to anything else. The main advantage is that is self-contained, but you have to recompile it on every different architecture (32bit, arm processors, ...) and operating system (windows, linux, macos) - it's the operating system that take cares of redirecting input and output on cli.

Ruby, instead, is interpreted. There is a program called "Ruby interpreter" which translates your code to the appropriate machine code on the fly. It's a different approach, it's more "high level".
The advantage is that you don't need to recompile the code. However, the  "Ruby interpreter" itself must be written in some compiled language.

Comment: The word translate on the fly to the interpreter is correct but more closely put, It doesn't translate, It has every program within interpreter, Interpreter is the program which actually runs on the machine and our program is going to be the input to the interpreter program.